# Mount USB (FAT) in Gentoo

Tags: mount, usb, fat

Can somebody show me how to make Gentoo mount my USB? This is what I got when trying `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

`dmesg` says:

> FAT: codepage cp437 not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set codepage and charset in kernel options:

```
make menuconfig -> File systems:
-> Native language support:
<*>   Codepage 437 (United States, Canada)
<*>   NLS ISO 8859-1  (Latin 1; Western European Languages)

-> DOS/FAT/NT Filesystems
(437) Default codepage for FAT
(iso8859-1) Default iocharset for FAT
```

and then recompile kernel...

Comment: just got this fixed by checking all available NLS and codepages :)

Comment: I'd add to this, that the options are country-dependent. Values in place of `iso8859-1` and `437` differ for different regions.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you do not have the "codepage cp437" support in the kernel.

Try to Look inside your /proc/config.gz file and search for a line like `CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_437=m` or `CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_437=y`. If you do not find it, you'll have to recompile the kernel to add the needed module.

Comment: some progress, right now it's saying `FAT: IO charset iso8859-1 not found`

Comment: you have to add also "NLS ISO 8859-1" support to your kernel. :-/ Probably, 437 is your default codepage and 8859-1 is the real usb-stick encoding (so you need both).

Answer (score -1):

First, make the mountpoint:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/udisk
```

Then, mount the USB drive, specifying the filesystem:

```
$ mount -t vfat -o defaults,utf8 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/udisk
```

If it were NTFS, you could use:

```
$ mount -t ntfs-3g -o defaults,utf8 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/udisk
```

Or for ISOs:

```
$ mount -o loop diskimage.iso /mnt/iso
```