# Unable to mount FAT32 USB drive in Mint ("is not a block device")

Tags: linux-mint, mount, usb-drive

I've been trying to mount a USB drive that's formatted as FAT32, and getting an error. The drive works fine on Windows machines.

When I try to mount it with `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usbdev`, I get

```
mount:  /dev/sdb1 is not a block device.
```

When I try to mount /dev/sdb to the same place (`sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb /media/usbdev`), I get

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I've tried Googling around and searching this site. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/mount-usb-fat-in-gentoo?rq=1) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72490/usb-mount-doesnt-work-on-centos-6-4) seem like the most relevant questions, but the solutions proposed there haven't worked. I've tried adding a line to /etc/fstab (`/dev/sdb1 /media/usbdev vfat defaults 0 0`), also to no avail. I'm pretty confused - what's going on, and what can I do to mount this USB drive? I'd rather not reformat it since I have some important data on there.

---

Here's what `lsblk` returns:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb                     8:16   1  29.9G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                  8:17   1  29.9G  0 part  
sda                     8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk  
├─sda2                  8:2    0   488M  0 part  /boot
├─sda3                  8:3    0 118.3G  0 part  
│ └─sda3_crypt        253:0    0 118.3G  0 crypt 
│   ├─mint--vg-root   253:1    0 110.4G  0 lvm   /
│   └─mint--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   7.9G  0 lvm   
│     └─cryptswap1    253:3    0   7.9G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─sda1                  8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
```

And here's the relevant portion of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 29.9 GiB, 32078036992 bytes, 62652416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot Start End       Sectors  Size   Id Type
/dev/sdb1       96    62652415  62652320 29.9G  c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

`dmesg |tail` shows the following:

```
[152334.491944]  sdb: sdb1 [152334.493759] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached
SCSI removable disk [153063.602803]  sdb: sdb1
```

So, it seems like the device is being recognized - it just won't mount.

I'm new to Linux, so please let me know if I should provide more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try mounting with -t fat and -o fat=32

Comment: @RamanSailopal No luck... `sudo mount -t fat /dev/sdb1 /media/usbdev` returns
    `mount: unknown filesystem type 'fat'`
and `sudo mount -o fat=32 /dev/sdb1 /media/usbdev` returns
    `mount:  /dev/sdb1 is not a block device`

Comment: Returns what? What's the message returned and the output from dmesg?

Comment: `dmesg | tail` shows `
[158362.425970] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 62652416 512-byte logical blocks: (32.1 GB/29.9 GiB)
[158362.426678] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[158362.426680] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[158362.427394] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[158362.430942] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 7 ep 4 with no TDs queued?
[158362.432276]  sdb: sdb1
[158362.433792] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
`

Comment: `fat` isn't a Linux filesystem type, you want `vfat`.  (the older one is `msdos`).  See `man mount`, "fat is not a separate filesystem,  but  a  common  part  of  the  msdos, umsdos and vfat filesystems".

Comment: @sourcejedi `ls -l /dev/sdb1` returns `cr-------- 1 root root 8, 17 Aug  3 15:37 /dev/sdb1`. I'll try rebooting.

edit: Rebooting worked! Thanks! `ls -l /dev/sdb1` now returns `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Aug  5 01:10 /dev/sdb1` Can I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: Done.  wow, something overrwrote it with a character device with the same major and minor number (8, 17) :-D.  That's so weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is not a block device" is pretty specific.  It suggests you've accidentally overwritten the block device with a regular file at some point. In this case, `ls -l /dev/sdb1` will show something other than `b` in the first column.  Here's an example from my system:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda1
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 1 Aug  3 08:32 /dev/sda1
```

`-` in the first column means a regular file.  `d` is a directory.  `b` is a block device node.  `c` is a character device node.  `p` is a named pipe.  `s` should be a named unix socket, I think.

This particular problem should go away if you just reboot.  `/dev/` is a tmpfs, it is recreated from scratch on each boot.